# how to play animation frame by frame

Tags: actionscript-3

I am having 5 scenes of animation. I want to combine those scenes to make
one file. Each file contains one scene(i.e. one movie clip which contains animation
of that scene).
   In order to prepare one file of all the scenes I have copied all the frames in
one file one by one. And used

> gotoAndPlay(2);

command for each frame. But after playing third frame it is again playing the
second frame and not the forth one. What changes should I make in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have put `gotoAndPlay(2);` on each frame, which obviously means to play 2nd frame even after the 3rd one.

Use [nextFrame()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#nextFrame%28%29) instead.

You could have used [nextScene()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#nextScene%28%29) as well & not altered the scenes at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I have written gotoAndPlay(4) on third frame and so on. Even nextFrame() and nextScene() is not working.

Comment: gotoAndPlay(<next frame number>) has no meaning... You could be just writing play() instead. What is the problem you face with nextFrame()?

Comment: the problem with nextFrame() is, it is not playing the first frame itself. Instead it is showing the last frame(first scene of last frame). Ok I'll try play() function now

Comment: now after using play () function, it is showing all the frames one after another without playing any animation

Comment: ok. now when I used play() function, it is working for first two frames, and not for the third frame. (Even after copying the code its not working) Is it possible that the problem is with movie clip or animation ?

Comment: do you have any other code on that 3rd frame? Maybe there is another gotoAndPlay() call there.